# How do I apply Zernike coefficients to a wavefront?

Tags: optics, imaging

I have been using the textbook "Numerical Simulation of Optical Wave Propagation with Examples in Matlab" (pdf available online: https://www.academia.edu/42684537/Numerical_Simulation_of_Optical_Wave_Propagation_With_examples_in_MATLAB).
I have been using chapter 5 to apply abberations to a wavefront using Matlab. The light source I am using is a coherent circular source that has passed through a lens and will then propagate. My intention is to apply the Zernike coefficients as in the example in this textbook (listing 5.4) after the lens and then propagate the light source afterwards. Is this correct - i.e. should the application of the aberration be applied directly after the lens? The Zernike coefficients are computed using Zemax if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think Zemax computers computes aberrations in the exit pupil plane. If you are simulating a single thin lens, you should apply the Zernike polynomial as part of the lens's complex pupil (transmittance) function.